# Android SDK issue while implementation to other project because of dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

In SDK we use iso parser library for video compression and few other things. It works fine in a test project, but when I try to use the snapshot version in another project iso parser does not work as it should. That is, while video compression it drops the audio. I don't know why, but when I configure it like this all works fine:

```
implementation('com.name.lib:Library:1.2.19-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'com.googlecode.mp4parser', module: 'isoparser'
}

implementation('com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6') {
    force = true
}
```

I know it's not good practice to use this type of snippet for lib dependenies. Is there any solution to this? If you need more details, please let me know.

Someone below told me to add this in proguard so.

```
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.isoparser.** { *; }
```

Comment: I’m afraid, I don’t understand what the issue is. Do you get any errors or so? Can you maybe elaborate on the differences between your “in testing” scenario and your “implement snapshot version” scenario?

Comment: Okay, We have snapshot version of our SDK and in this SDK there is feature for video compression and for we use `mp4parser` library as i mention `implementation ('com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6')` this library we use . **Problem statement:**  when we implement our `SNAPSHOT` version to other projects then it `mp4parser`  library not works properly like it drops audio while compression and i know the reason of it because our snapshot version library can't fetch all classes and methods to other projects because of decoding of code and when i use above syntax as exclude it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide build `--scan`s of both versions, working and non-working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with not using `isoparser` library in our SDK.

For most cases it can solve using keep method in `proguard` but in my case it didn't help me so i just removed isoparser from my SDK because of that now i don't have any `Duplication` error in other projects and now it not throw error like `noclassfound`

While using dependecny in SDK it headache for SDK user because of this two errors

- `Duplication` dependency found duplicate method while compiling that's conflict sdk
- `no class found` in some case project it's fails to find some class of dependency that used in my SDK because Android studio not decomile whole SDK

> Conclusion : Try to not use any famous third party library in SDK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should keep All your classes related to the `com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6` library in your proGuard.

I think it's a proGaurd issue and you probably must write a proGaurd or Consumer rule.

add this to your library progaurd rule and your app progaurd rule and check again:

```
-keep class com.coremedia.iso.** {*;}
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.** {*;}
-keep class com.mp4parser.** {*;}

-keep class * implements com.coremedia.iso.boxes.Box { *; }
-dontwarn com.coremedia.iso.boxes.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.mjpeg.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.ttml.**

-dontwarn com.coremedia.**
-dontwarn com.googlecode.mp4parser.**
```

Comment: I already keep all classes that i'm importing in proguard

Comment: I edit my answer plz check it out and let me know what happened.

Comment: It can solved issue because gradle minify project some method will not accessible for SDK . Thanks for that but i already know about `minifyenabled false` and `keep` in progured

Comment: If i use `dontwarn` it will be not a safe way to implement isoparser